# Tic Tak Toe game logic using Artificial Intelligence using JAVA

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I want to develop a logic for tic-tak-toe game using JAVA language(Standalone program only, no UI).
Concept is, game will play between human and machine(Artificial Intelligence).
can you please guide me.

Thanks in advance :)

Regards,
Subaan

Comment: SO is a QA Website and not there to guide people to solve whole projects

Comment: What is the difficuly needed? Do you have some code already made? What do you need to know precisely? What is your question?

Comment: Thanks Alex, 
Currently i am analysis phase. I am expecting guidence from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tic-tak-toe is so computationally simple, you could just search the whole problem space exhaustively using mini-max.

[Here is a post I found using google search](http://hannahaddad-blog.blogspot.ca/2014/04/implmenting-minimax-algorithm-on-tic.html) detailing how to do this in java.  I reviewed the article and it includes :

- detailed code of how to get it working
- great images of how to imagine and picture the computation
- step by step conceptual walk through of how the problem can be solved
- it is command line, like you asked

Comment: Thank you wontonimo

Comment: Blog in the link has been removed

Answer (score 0):

For game playing, the minimax algorithm is usefull. You should be able to find plenty of imformation about it.

Comment: Thanks Thijs Steel, Can you please suggests any other algorithms like minmax..... helpful for me

Comment: There are some variations on minmax like alfabeta pruning. But while these are more efficiënt. They should give the same result. So i suggest you start with that

Comment: I believe you mean *alpha-beta* pruning. It is guaranteed to give exactly the same results as mini-max, with the only difference being that it requires a lot less computing resources.

Comment: yes, that's what i said right?